# Assigning a reference number to exceptions logged using Elmah MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

We have an Asp.Net MVC application and are using Elmah for logging and handling unhandled exceptions.

There is a new requirement that a reference no. should be provided to the user on 500-Internal Server Error page which the user may report to the support team and then the support team may look for the provided reference number in the Elmah log.

How can it be done? We are using custom error pages. Please ask if the question is not clear. Thank you.

Comment: have u tried any code?

Comment: I downloaded the source for Elmah but I cannot figure out where to assign the reference number and how to customize the elmah.axd page to accommodate the reference number there.